# Style object based on binding bool attribute in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can change the fill color of an object I'm being to in my mvvm setup using xaml in wpf.  I want to change the fill color to red when the attribute being bound to is set to True.

The attribute is called IsRound.

I'll post code if necessary. I'm not on a pc at the moment.

UPDATED

Could someone show an example of how to do this using style triggers?
And set the value based on the bind property bool?

Comment: Plz check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an IValueConverter on the binding.

```
BackgroundColor="{Binding Path=IsRound, Converter={StaticResource BoolToFillColorConverter}}"

public class BoolToFillColorConverter: IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      bool b;
      if (bool.TryParse(value, out b))
      {
        if (b) return Red
        else return Blue;
      }
      else
      {
        return SomeDefaultColour;
      }
  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't I just use a style setter triggger? And set the value based on the bind property bool?

Comment: Yes, that would work too. The ValueConverter gives you the ability for more complex logic and testability.

Comment: Could you show a demo using the other method as well. So I could see both examples please ?

Answer (score 18):

First of all you don't need any `Binding` for what you are trying to do. `DataTrigger` is enough. In the example below `IsCyan` is a `boolean` property of `ViewModel`. But `Background` of `TextBlock` is not bound at all.

```
           <TextBlock Text="Inside content">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCyan}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkCyan"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCyan}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
```

But if at all you need Binding, solution by the user **benPearce** to use `Converter` is the way to go.