# LED (Red/Green) in WPF bound to a function

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a Red/Green LED to my WPF UI. My XAML file and the class details are given below.

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" Name="FVDataBinding">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="  Status: " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <Ellipse x:Name="StatusEllipse" Fill="#388E3C" Height="20" Stroke="Black" Width="20"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My class implementation is below

```
public class MyStatus
{
     private string m_Name;
     private bool m_status;

     public bool Status
     {
            get { return m_status; }
            set { m_status = value; }
     }
}
```

How do I link my `StatusEclipse` to the function status where `true` for `Green` and `false` for `Red`

Comment: You need a converter that will convert true/false to Red/Green.

Comment: A converter, as @Nikhil recommends, for this scenario is overkill. All you really need is a `Style` with a `Setter` (for the default color) and a `DataTrigger` (for the non-default color). You can make either `true` or `false` the default trigger; just use the other value for the `Value` of the `DataTrigger`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34489299) for a variation where both colors are set by triggers (not required, but it's another way to do it).

Comment: You can also use `Style` and `Triggers` to do this. with no additional files for converters! Pure XAML.

Answer (score 3):

You need a converter that will convert true/false to Red/Green.

**In Xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <foobar:StatusConverter x:Key="StatusConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Ellipse x:Name="StatusEllipse" Fill="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter}}" Height="20" Stroke="Black" Width="20"/>
```

**In CS**

```
public class StatusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(.....)
    {
        //Check for value and return a SolidColorBrush instance.
    }

    public object ConvertBack(.....)
    {
        throw NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Agarwal - what is `foobar` ?

Comment: @liv2hak: That's the namespace which you have where this converter is located.